# Styling Android action bar and PullToRefresh component

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar-compat

I am using ActionBar (Compat) version of PullToRefresh library (https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) in my Holo Light application.

See https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10057117/ns_bnp_dev/styles.png to see my basic layout.

Now my customer asked me to change the blue color of selected tab in action bar and blue color of indeterminate progress bar that is shown by pulling the list down (part of PullToRefresh component).

I failed to find some easy way to do so.

I am able to change the background of tabs in actionbar by creating new drawable resource for whole background. I believe there must be some more easy way just specifying the color.

I am not able to change the color of the progress bar, PullToRefresh's ptrProgressBarColor attribute applies only to progress shown when in pulling gesture.

Anyone has the experience with re-styling any of these?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the indeterminate progress bar, 
change the

```
<color name="default_progress_bar_color"> #FF33B5E5 </color>
```

in the colors.xml of the PullToRefresh library.

Comment: It is extremely bad taste to reject helpful edits and then apply those yourself.